# How to execute TeX only for side effects

Tags: macros, tex-core, grouping, output

I need to execute a part of my *T<sub>E</sub>X* code without printing the text it produces while making `\global` macros defined by it available.

For example, when I have this group:

```
{
  foo\global\def\bar{baz}
}
```

I want to make the `\bar` macro available but not to print the word `foo`.

Comment: Try `\sbox0{foo\global\def\bar{baz}}`  Note that only global definitions are saved.

Comment: Would you please make an example of use with some motivation?